# extension classes and Galois cohomology

Tags: gr.group-theory, nt.number-theory

Let $K$ be a field, and $G_{K}$ the absolute Galois group of $K$, $A,C$ are abelian groups with continuous $G_{K}$-actions.

Suppose that $B$ is an extension, i.e., there is a short exact sequence

$0 \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow C \longrightarrow 0$

as $G_{K}$-module.

Does there exists

{the isomorphic classes of extension classes} $\cong H^{1}(G_{K}, Hom_{G_{K}-con}(C,A))$ ?

Comment: Not in general. There's a spectral sequence $H^i(G,Ext^j(C,A))\implies Ext^n(C,A)$ where the left hand Ext is as abelian groups (if $C$ is finitely generated). See, for example, the first section of Milne's book on Arithmetic Duality Theorems.